# Memory comparison causes system halt

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am working on a kernel module and I need to compare two buffers to find out if they are equivalent. I am using the memcmp function defined in the Linux kernel to do so. My first buffer is like this:

```
cache_buffer = (unsigned char *)vmalloc(4097);
cache_buffer[4096] = '/0';
```

The second buffer is from a page using the page_address() function.

```
page = bio_page(bio);
kmap(page);
write_buffer = (char *)page_address(page);
kunmap(page);
```

I have printed the contents of both buffers before hand and not only to they print correctly, but they also have the same content. So next, I do this:

```
result = memcmp(write_buffer, cache_buffer, 2048); // only comparing up to 2048 positions
```

This causes the kernel to freeze up and I cannot figure out why. I checked the implementation of memcmp and saw nothing that would cause the freeze. Can anyone suggest a cause?

Here is the memcmp implementation:

```
int memcmp(const void *cs, const void *ct, size_t count)
{
    const unsigned char *su1, *su2;
    int res = 0;

    for (su1 = cs, su2 = ct; 0 < count; ++su1, ++su2, count--)
           if ((res = *su1 - *su2) != 0)
                     break;
    return res;
}
```

EDIT: The function causing the freeze is memcmp. When I commented it out, everything worked. Also, when I did I memcmp as follows

```
memcmp(write_buffer, write_buffer, 2048); //comparing two write_buffers
```

Everything worked as well. Only when I throw the cache_buffer into the mix is when I get the error. Also, above is a simplification of my actual code. Here is the entire function:

```
static int compare_data(sector_t location, struct bio * bio, struct cache_c * dmc)
{
struct dm_io_region where;
unsigned long bits;
int segno;
struct bio_vec * bvec;
struct page * page;
unsigned char * cache_data;
    char * temp_data;
char * write_data;
int result, length, i;

cache_data = (unsigned char *)vmalloc((dmc->block_size * 512) + 1);

where.bdev = dmc->cache_dev->bdev;
where.count = dmc->block_size;
where.sector = location << dmc->block_shift;

printk(KERN_DEBUG "place: %llu\n", where.sector);

dm_io_sync_vm(1, &where, READ, cache_data, &bits, dmc);

length = 0;

bio_for_each_segment(bvec, bio, segno)
{
    if(segno == 0)
    {
        page = bio_page(bio);
        kmap(page);
        write_data = (char *)page_address(page);
        //kunmap(page);
        length += bvec->bv_len;
    }
    else
    {
        page = bio_page(bio);
        kmap(page);
        temp_data = strcat(write_data, (char *)page_address(page));
        //kunmap(page);
        write_data = temp_data;
        length += bvec->bv_len;
    }
}

printk(KERN_INFO "length: %u\n", length);

cache_data[dmc->block_size * 512] = '\0';

for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
{
    printk("%c", write_data[i]);
}

printk("\n");

for(i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
{
    printk("%c", cache_data[i]);
}

printk("\n");    

result = memcmp(write_data, cache_data, length);

return result;    
}
```

EDIT #2: Sorry guys. The problem was not memcmp. It was the result of memcmp. When ever it returned a positive or negative number, the function that called my function would play with some pointers, one of which was uninitialized. I don't know why I didn't realize it before. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem but you wrote '/0' instead of '\0'. Try fixing this.

Comment: Have you identified precisely which function freezes the kernel ? If so, please edit your question to explicit this. Otherwise, just try adding some `printk`s or run your kernel through a debugger (the second solution is much longer to set up, but once done it will help you a lot :) )

Comment: it is definitely memcmp, but only when the cache_buffer is involved

Comment: If you `memcmp(a, a, anything)` memcmp can short circuit and return 0 immediately, because obviously `a[0]` is always the same as `a[0]`, `a[1]` is the same as `a[1]`, and so on.  So it's no surprise that it only fails when the first two arguments to `memcmp` differ.

Comment: I guess the two printk loops don't lead to any problem, so the two pointers should be valid, if you get an Oops, could you show us the log ?

Comment: I do not get an Oops. When the kernel freezes, nothing is written to the logs about the error. Is there a way I can ensure that any errors are written to the logs before the crash?

Comment: This symptom is usually the consequence of a deadlock. I find very strange the fact that only reading memory freezes the kernel.

Comment: Can you do a memcmp between two unique vmalloc() buffers?  Extreme as it sounds, any chance you have a broken, optimized implementation of memcmp()   (depends on hardware features your actual cpu doesn't have, makes bad mmu assumptions, etc)

Answer (score 7):

I'm no kernel expert, but I would assume you need to keep this memory mapped while doing the comparison? In other words, don't call `kunmap` until after the `memcmp` is complete. I would presume that calling it before will result in `write_buffer` pointing to a page which is no longer mapped.

Taking your code in the other question, here is a rough attempt at incremental. Still needs some cleanup, I'm sure:

```
static int compare_data(sector_t location, struct bio * bio, struct cache_c * dmc)
{
  struct dm_io_region where;
  unsigned long bits;
  int segno;
  struct bio_vec * bvec;
  struct page * page;
  unsigned char * cache_data;
  char * temp_data;
  char * write_data;
  int length, i;

  int result = 0;
  size_t position = 0;
  size_t max_size = (dmc->block_size * 512) + 1;

  cache_data = (unsigned char *)vmalloc(max_size);

  where.bdev = dmc->cache_dev->bdev;
  where.count = dmc->block_size;
  where.sector = location << dmc->block_shift;

  printk(KERN_DEBUG "place: %llu\n", where.sector);

  dm_io_sync_vm(1, &where, READ, cache_data, &bits, dmc);

  bio_for_each_segment(bvec, bio, segno)
  {
    // Map the page into memory
    page = bio_page(bio);
    write_data = (char *)kmap(page);
    length = bvec->bv_len;

    // Make sure we don't go past the end
    if(position >= max_size)
      break;
    if(position + length > max_size)
      length = max_size - position;

    // Compare the data
    result = memcmp(write_data, cache_data + position, length);
    position += length;

    kunmap(page);

    // If the memory is not equal, bail out now and return the result
    if(result != 0)
      break;
  }

  cache_data[dmc->block_size * 512] = '\0';

  return result;    
}
```

Comment: The following link might be helpful : http://kneuro.net/linux-mm/index.php?file=kmap.html ... If I understand it correctly, it confirms your opinion about this problem.

Comment: You can also write it thusly: `write_buffer = kmap(page);` This may help the clarity of *map/use/unmap*

Comment: This solution is problematic because according to what I understand, a bio may have many segments. I want to loop over these segments and concatenate them together into one string. If have to leave each segment mapped, I would need to keep pointers to them to unmap them later. Furthermore, would writing the data into my own buffer take care of that issue anyways?

Comment: You don't have a choice in the matter. You have to keep the pages mapped until you're done with them, whether "done" means doing your comparison or copying it to another buffer. How about doing an incremental comparison?

Comment: I have tried keeping the pages mapped, but the outcome did not change. I will try an incremental comparison.

Comment: I have added a rough approximation of what the code should look like for incremental comparison.

Comment: No dice. It halted with this as well. I commented out memcmp in a second attempt to confirm that it was the problem and it is.